# Renaming Array Sub-Documents In an Aggregation Result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb 3.4. After running my aggregation, my result is shown as follow. I did a join between two collections.

```
[   {
    "_id": { // rename _id to main
      "id": "ID_001",
      "name": "Fred flinstone Inc"
    },
    "types": [
      {
        "typeId": "TYPE1",
        "locations": [
          {
            "locationName": "Sydney", // rename locationName to name
            "units": [
              {
                "unitId": "PHG_BTG1" // remove the unitId, i just want the value
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "locationName": "Brisbane",
            "units": [
              {
                "unitId": "PHG_KTN1"
              },
              {
                "unitId": "PHG_KTN2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   } ]
```

I want to project it as

```
[
  {
    "main": {
      "id": "ID_001",
      "name": "Fred flinstone Inc"
    },
    "types": [
      {
        "typeId": "TYPE1",
        "locations": [
          {
            "name": "Sydney",
            "units": [
              "PHG_BTG1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Brisbane",
            "units": [
              "PHG_KTN1",
              "PHG_KTN2"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do this? I tried various combinations of $project but failed. 
Example

```
{ $project: {
  main: "$_id",
  "_id": 0,
  "types.locations.name": "$types.locations.locationName"
}}
```

will rename the locations.name correctly but the value shows an array of [Sydney, Brisbane] . Ditto when I tried something similar to locations.units.

I tried to unwind again but it will show me an empty result. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) alone only really does "inclusive" or "exclusive" in the form you are attempting to use it. So whilst you can do `"types": { "typeId": 1 }` to only return those items of an array, you cannot actually change the underlying structure merely by "inclusion" or "exclusion".

Also as you discovered, something like:

```
{ "$project": {
  "types.locations.units": "$types.locations.units.unitId"   
}}
```

comes out different to what you were expecting since MongoDB views each  value and as a "mapped" array element:

```
"types" : [ 
    {
        "locations" : [ 
            {
                "units" : [ 
                    [ 
                        [ 
                            "PHG_BTG1"
                        ], 
                        [ 
                            "PHG_KTN1", 
                            "PHG_KTN2"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
```

Or worse:

```
{ "$project": {
  "types.typeId": "$types.typeId"
}}
```

As:

```
"types" : [ 
    {
        "typeId" : [ 
            "TYPE1"
        ]
    }
]
```

So "arrays of arrays" is not really wanted here. Which brings us to why this is actually "shorthand" for using the following operator you really want to use.

To "transform" arrays, you use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
{ "$project": {
  "_id": 0,
  "main": "$_id",
  "types": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$types",
      "as": "t",
      "in": {
        "typeId": "$$t.typeId",
        "locations": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$$t.locations",
            "as": "l",
            "in": {
              "name": "$$l.locationName",
              "units": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$l.units",
                  "as": "u",
                  "in": "$$u.unitId"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Which returns the format you want:

```
{
    "main" : {
        "id" : "ID_001",
        "name" : "Fred flinstone Inc"
    },
    "types" : [ 
        {
            "typeId" : "TYPE1",
            "locations" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Sydney",
                    "units" : [ 
                        "PHG_BTG1"
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Brisbane",
                    "units" : [ 
                        "PHG_KTN1", 
                        "PHG_KTN2"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially each "array" is "re-mapped" into just returning the structure of it's internal representation that you actually specify. This is why you nest [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) inside of other [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) expressions, to deal with the internal arrays to each array element.

Note also that since we are essentially "re-writing" the `"type"` property, the default behavior of properties with the same name in [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) would normally be to "copy" and retain order, being `"types"` actually is part of the existing document structure where `"main"` is not. So `"types"` would be represented "first" by standard projection inclusion.

The "re-writing" means this is considered a new element, and thus the order of keys is now the same as in the projection, being that `"main"` preceeds `"type"`, and not the other way around.